# Difference between reverse() and reversed() in swift

Tags: swift

Code1:

```
let word = "Backwards"
for char in word.reversed() {
    print(char, terminator: "")
}
```

Code 2:

```
var characters: [Character] = ["C", "a", "f", "é"]
characters.reverse()
print(characters)
```

What is the difference between these two codes?

Comment: `reverse` changes the object (also called "destructive operation", because the original isn't available any more), `reversed` makes a new object ("non-destructive operation").

Comment: You wrote the code. What part don't you understand?

Comment: No, the output is very different. The two blocks do two completely different things. So yes, there is a significant difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an important missing aspect of `reverse` and `reversed` are their time complexities.

Apart from the fact that `reverse` is mutating function defined over a collection and `reversed` returns a new object altogether, the time complexity of `reverse` is **O(n)** and `reversed` is **O(1)**.

**O(1)** time complexity seems surprising but if we look at the return type of `reversed` call it returns `ReversedCollection` object which internally points to the original collection unless original contents are modified. So basically it is just presenting/accessing the elements of the base collection in reversed manner to save time and memory.

Following example shows that reversed array remains same as the original array unless it is modified:

```
var originalArray = [1, 2, 3]
var reversedArray = originalArray.reversed()

print("0th index of OriginalArray \(originalArray[0])")
print("0th index of ReversedBaseArray \(reversedArray._base[0])")


print("0th index of OriginalArray \(originalArray.first)")
print("0th index of ReversedBaseArray \(reversedArray.first)")

originalArray[0] = 4 // Modification makes a separate copy of each instance
print("0th index of OriginalArray \(originalArray[1])")
print("0th index of ReversedBaseArray \(reversedArray._base[1])")


// Console Output:
// 0th index of OriginalArray 1
// 0th index of ReversedBaseArray 1


// First element of OriginalArray Optional(1)
// First element of ReversedBaseArray Optional(3)


// 0th index of OriginalArray 4
// 0th index of ReversedBaseArray 1
```

Answer (score 3):

**reversed()**

return completely new array with reversed order of original

**reverse()**

reverse collection it self.

Comment: `reversed()` returns a *collection,* not an array.

Answer (score 2):

You yourself exposed the difference perfectly. All you have to do is look at your own code.

- `characters.reverse()` changes the value of `characters`.
- But `word.reversed()` leaves `word` unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

**Below are the differences**

> Code1: create an iterator to traverse in reverse order

```
let word = "Backwards" 
    for char in word.reversed() {
        print(char, terminator: "") 
}
```

> Code 2: reverse the content

```
var characters: [Character] = ["C", "a", "f", "é"]
characters.reverse()
print(characters)
```